# Trying to connect to hyper V-VMs ( with Powershell) and extract data

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, hyper-v

Greeting!
I get the error message:

> PSSession: Connecting to Remote Server xxx failed with the following
> error message: The followig error occured while using Kerberos
> authentification:Cannot find the computer xxx Verify that the computer
> exists on the network

my code:

```
$as=get-clustergroup | sort-object name
foreach ($e in $as)
{ $s=New-PSSession -Computername $e.name
  Invoke-command -Session $s -ScriptBlock{Get-Service *}
  Exit-Session
}
```

I want to loop through all VMs on a cluster and check whether the  (virtual) hard drive is full or to list the running processes

Comment: The .Name property from `Get-ClusterGroup` is.. well.. the name of the ClusterGroup. Most likely, this is **not** the same as the name of the computer.

Comment: in our environment its giving back a list of our  vms